# SCons does not ignore dependencies

Tags: dependencies, scons

I have the following file system structure

```
+-sources+-A
|          + source files 
|        +-B
|          + source files 
|        +-C
|          + source files 
|
sharedLib
     +-libA.so
     +-libB.so
     +-libC.so
```

The libB.so depends on libC.so. The libA.so depends on libB.so

By default, SCons rebuilds all three libraries if a file under sources/C directory changes. I need to rebuild only the **libC.so** shared library and not to touch two others.
I tried adding `environment.Ignore('sharedLib/libB.so', 'sharedLib/libC.so')` but it did not help.

Comment: Please show us your SConstruct/SConscripts such that we get an idea of how you setup the build. You might also want to try the command line option `--debug=explain` (check out the MAN page) to find out more about WHY SCons thinks your targets need a rebuild.

Comment: I cannot show my Sconstruct as it does not exist. The relevant commands are generated on the fly by a Python script running inside SCons instead of static Sconstruct.

Comment: Well, the script with the generating commands would do fine too. Or you try to derive a simple MWE with a similar structure as used in your script and post that. Maybe you can use Kenneth's initial answer as a starting point for this?

Comment: I really cannot put my script here. It is a commercial product and I'm prohibited from publishing any specific details.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [Requires](http://scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x1261.html) function...

This appears to work just fine in a minimal example I put together demonstrating your use case...

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.6.rel_2.3.5:3347:d31d5a4e74b6[MODIFIED], 2015/07/31 14:36:10, by bdbaddog on hpmicrodog
    engine: v2.3.6.rel_2.3.5:3347:d31d5a4e74b6[MODIFIED], 2015/07/31 14:36:10, by bdbaddog on hpmicrodog
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2015 The SCons Foundation

>> tree  
.
├── SConstruct
├── sharedLib
└── sources
    ├── A
    │   └── libA.cpp
    ├── B
    │   └── libB.cpp
    └── C
        └── libC.cpp

5 directories, 4 files

>> cat SConstruct 
import os
env = Environment()
libC = env.SharedLibrary('sharedLib/libC.so', 'sources/C/libC.cpp')
envAB = env.Clone()
envAB.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-lC'],
             LIBPATH=['sharedLib'])
libA = envAB.SharedLibrary('sharedLib/libA.so', 'sources/A/libA.cpp')
envAB.Requires(libA, libC)
libB = envAB.SharedLibrary('sharedLib/libB.so', 'sources/B/libB.cpp')
envAB.Requires(libB, libC)

>> cat sources/A/libA.cpp 
#include <iostream>
void A(void) {std::cout << "A" << std::endl;}

>> cat sources/B/libB.cpp
#include <iostream>
void B(void) {std::cout << "B" << std::endl;}

>> cat sources/C/libC.cpp
#include <iostream>
void C(void) {std::cout << "C" << std::endl;}

>> scons                 
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o sources/C/libC.os -c -fPIC sources/C/libC.cpp
g++ -o sharedLib/libC.so -shared sources/C/libC.os
g++ -o sources/A/libA.os -c -fPIC sources/A/libA.cpp
g++ -o sharedLib/libA.so -lC -shared sources/A/libA.os -LsharedLib
g++ -o sources/B/libB.os -c -fPIC sources/B/libB.cpp
g++ -o sharedLib/libB.so -lC -shared sources/B/libB.os -LsharedLib
scons: done building targets.

>> tree
.
├── SConstruct
├── sharedLib
│   ├── libA.so
│   ├── libB.so
│   └── libC.so
└── sources
    ├── A
    │   ├── libA.cpp
    │   └── libA.os
    ├── B
    │   ├── libB.cpp
    │   └── libB.os
    └── C
        ├── libC.cpp
        └── libC.os

5 directories, 10 files

>> echo "void E(void){}" >> sources/C/libC.cpp

>> cat sources/C/libC.cpp 
#include <iostream>
void C(void) {std::cout << "C" << std::endl;}
void E(void){}

>> scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o sources/C/libC.os -c -fPIC sources/C/libC.cpp
g++ -o sharedLib/libC.so -shared sources/C/libC.os
scons: done building targets.

>> tree
.
├── SConstruct
├── sharedLib
│   ├── libA.so
│   ├── libB.so
│   └── libC.so
└── sources
    ├── A
    │   ├── libA.cpp
    │   └── libA.os
    ├── B
    │   ├── libB.cpp
    │   └── libB.os
    └── C
        ├── libC.cpp
        └── libC.os

5 directories, 10 files
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help

Comment: Can you elaborate?  If I understand your question, libA and libB link against libC, but you want a source code change to libC to only trigger a re-build of libC.  That is what this MWE does...

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. What really happens is that all three libraries are relinked when I change a source file of libC. Neither Ignore nor Requires help. I've actually solved this but removing the libA and libB targets from the build. I did it by producing the dependency tree and analyzing it. As I've said to  dirkbaechle, the SCons commands are generated on the fly and I've modified the script to issue commands for libraries that have to be built.